# Lua neovim plugin load nvim_buf_clear_namespace when textchange

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

I started using neovim recently and for a learning Example i tried to create a basic plugin to update packages for node modules inside the `package.json`

The idea is when the `text changes` or when trying to `undo` i clear the buffer.

Calling this function : `lua Clear_highlights()` do the job but it's seems when the `text changes` or `undo` seems not triggering the function `Clear_highlights()` am for sure missing something if someone can help me catch this will be awesome.

Thank you.

line 20 : [Github repo](https://github.com/azizgharbi/nodePackageCheck.nvim/blob/main/plugin/init.lua)

```
-- Clear buffer
Clear_highlights = function()
    vim.api.nvim_buf_clear_namespace(0, require("nodePackageCheck").Config.get_namespace_id(), 0, -1)
end

vim.cmd([[autocmd! TextChanged,TextChangedI, BufWritePost  * lua Clear_highlights()]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vim.cmd([[autocmd! TextChanged,TextChangedI, BufWritePost  * lua Clear_highlights()]])
```

- `autocmd!` is for deleting handlers/groups, not defining them. Remove the bang (`!`).
- Random whitespace confuses vim's parser: here it treats `BufWritePost` as the "pattern", and `*` as the start of the handler (command).

Try this instead:

```
vim.cmd([[autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI,BufWritePost * lua Clear_highlights()]])
```

Comment: It does what i want thanks for the explaining.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was a remapping `undo` in normal mode and call `Clear_highlights()` with.

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "u", ":undo<CR>:lua Clear_highlights()<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
```